# How to activate hyphenation in \ttfamily without explictly setting a font?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, hyphenation, typewriter

I am suprised that in the code below no hyphenation is done.
And I can not find something about that on the web. Maybe I used the wrong words for searching.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{ttfamily}
\begin{tabu} spread \textwidth {X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]}
    A&
    B&
    Sichtweise, Haltung, Akzeptanz, useability, Anwenderfreundlichkeit&
    D\\
\end{tabu}
\end{ttfamily}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does `Anwenderfreundlichkeit` hyphenate in regular text?

Comment: LaTeX doesn't hyphenate typewriter type text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solves the problem.

```
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, LaTeX doesn't hyphenate typewriter type text.

With `fontspec` you can revert this decision quite easily, but you have to newly define a monospaced font.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}[HyphenChar={-}]

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{ttfamily}
\begin{tabu} spread \textwidth {X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]}
    A&
    B&
    Sichtweise, Haltung, Akzeptanz, useability, Anwenderfreundlichkeit&
    D\\
\end{tabu}
\end{ttfamily}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that `[HyphenChar={-}]` is needed, I get a font with hyphenation directly with `\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}`. As far as I can see fontspec sets hyphenchar to -1 only for the default lmtt.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Possibly, but I think it's clearer this way. Since legacy monospaced fonts all disable hyphenation, I can't exclude `fontspec` will do the same in the future.