# Problems adjusting typewriter fonts

Tags: margins, typewriter

I was doing my report, and I face to some problem with `typewriter` font; it was not adjusted to the text width. I don't find any related answer or topic.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\section{New Story}

A written line

\section{Another}

\begin{itemize}
\item Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  blah blah \texttt{RegistroSismico.xls}, blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\end{itemize}

Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  blah blah \texttt{RegistroSismico.xls}, blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solves the problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290800/29764

Answer (score 2):

If hyphenation is allowed, please compare corrected and uncorrected paragraph. The `\-`'s are the places, where hyphenation is allowed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\section{New Story}

A written line

\section{Another}

\begin{itemize}
\item Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  blah blah \texttt{Registro\-Sis\-mi\-co.xls}, blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\end{itemize}

Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  blah blah \texttt{RegistroSismico.xls}, blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]