# Awful text wrap with \ttfamily

Tags: line-breaking, typewriter

This might be a silly question but I cannot find a way to solve it. Below is a MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily
What can we do in this case? What should we do about this? What can we do in this case? What should we do about this?

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The result is like this:

[image: result]

As you can see, the right side is completely misaligned. I've tried to set the `\hyphenpenalty` but it seems to be useless.

How should one fix this?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290731/35864 help?

Comment: @moewe Thanks for this link. I think my question is almost the same with it, but the solution there doesn't work for me. It is probably because that I'm using `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to this:
[wordbreaking, justification and ttfamily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171278/wordbreaking-justification-and-ttfamily)

This might work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=`\-\spaceskip=.5em plus .5em\xspaceskip=.5em
    What can we do in this case? What should we do about this? What can we do in this case? What should we do about this?
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask what is `\spaceskip=.5em plus .5em\xspaceskip=.5em` for?

Comment: \spaceskip and \xspaceskip are ways to control interword spacing in ragged macros.
For example \spaceskip of 0.5em makes every interword space exactly 0.5em and xspaceskip is for the spacing between sentences.